# Error creating and accessing object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following declaration

```
function Func1(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
};
```

I'd like to create a place holder for an array of Func1 object. As far I as I see, i declared an array of items so it should have already been defined. But every time I tried to access the array, it gives me the "undefined" error.

```
var Func2 = function () {
    var items = [];

    this.addItem = function (a, b) {
        items.push(new Func1(a, b));
    }

    var function2 = new Func2();
    function2.addItem(2, 'test');
    window.alert(function2.items[0].b); // this gives error "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference. I'd like to be able to show 'test' here.
```

I also modified the code as to use declare 'this.items = []' instead of 'var items=[]', it gives me a different error, as follows:

```
 var Func3 = function () {
     this.items = [];

     this.addItem = function (a, b) {
         items.push(new Func1(a, b)); // this gives error 'items' is undefined
     }
 };

 var function3 = new Func3();
 function3.addItem(3, 'test'); 
 window.alert(function3.items[0].b); // I want to show 'test' here
```

I modified the addItem function again, still get error

```
var Func4 = function () {
    this.items = [];

    this.addItem = function (a, b) {
        items[items.length] = new Func1(a, b); // this gives error 'items' is undefined,  too
    }
};
```

I just couldn't find out why the code was failing, and Google search didn't help me much. I could have not used the right keyword to search but searching for "accessing array in javascript" doesn't give me any good result. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `this.items = [];`, then you should use `this.items` instead of just `items`. There is no global or local *variable* defined as `items` in the posted code and this is why you get such error.

```
this.items.push('...');
```

When you use `var items = [];` in the constructor, the variable is *local* to the constructor function, so external scope can't access the variable. You should either define a method that returns the value or define the `items` as an instance (object) property.

These are 2 options:

```
var Option1 = function () {
    var items = [];

    this.addItem = function (a, b) {
       items.push(new Func1(a, b));
    }

    this.getItems = function() {
       return items;
    }
}
```

And:

```
var Option2 = function () {
    this.items = [];

    this.addItem = function (a, b) {
       this.items.push(new Func1(a, b));
    }
}
```

Comment: Explanation instead of just handing over finished code. +1

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you!  There is still a lot of room for improvement here :)

Comment: Question: in option 1, why don't we need 'this.items'? Are they going to cause confusion with the global items (if any)?

Comment: @VietNguyen Because we are defining a variable, a local variable and not a property. This design pattern can be used for keeping a value _private_ so that external scope can not directly manipulate the value. In the second option the value is _exposed_ to the external scope as a property of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a scope issue, use "this" when declaring items and when invoking it. Check the snippet:

```js
function Func1(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
};

var Func2 = function () {
    this.items = [];

    this.addItem = function (a, b) {
        this.items.push(new Func1(a, b));
    }
}

var function2 = new Func2();
function2.addItem(2, 'test');
window.alert(function2.items[0].b);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the items to be hidden outside of the function, then you need to add a getter function in order to access to items variable:

```
function Func1(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
};

var Func2 = function () {
    var items = [];

    this.addItem = function (a, b) {
        items.push(new Func1(a, b));
    }

    this.getItem = function(index) {
      return items[index];
    };
}

var function2 = new Func2();
function2.addItem(2, 'test');
console.log(function2.getItem(0).b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid this context confusion in cases like this is to cache the self reference.

```
var Func2 = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.items = [] 

    self.addItem = function (a, b) {
        self.items.push(new Func1(a, b));
    }
}
```

This way, the correct context is curried into addItem(), and it should run no matter where it is called from.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the code:

- `var items`, only belongs to the constructor function so the instances won't get a copy of it. So use `this.items` in the constructor function (`Func2`) so when you create an instance of `Func2`, the instance has that instance variable.
- I see you sometimes use `items` and sometimes `this.items`, always use `this.items`. So in `Func3` and `Func4`, change the code to be like so:

  ```
  this.addItem = function (a, b) {
     this.items[items.length] = new Func1(a, b);  
  }
  ```

I hope that helps.

Comment: always use "this.items"? Yes, even in the bracket notation.